Creating a service block in Anylogic using Java
Is there any way to create a process service block using java?
pre conditions, there is an initial block source called "source";
the parameters of queue and delay time are in an excel file :
Service name data on column A starting on A2
Queue data on column B starting on B2
time data on column C starting on C2
Then place a sink block to finish.
I tried to look for more information on Anylogic help however it looks there is not enough info.
:(

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no need and it would not be good practice at all.
Instead, create an agent type with the Service block in it, use ports or Enter/Exit blocks and instantiate that agent type.
